# How to run python script on arm board with android pie?

Tags: android, python, adb, android-9.0-pie

I have python script and arm board with android pie.
I have UART console and adb shell of board. Now i want to run python script on board ?

How to add python packages in android build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To run python, we need to install QPython apk on the board, which has the necessary python binaries to run python, Download the QPython apk
2. Start the adb service on the board and connect to the host PC.
3. Install the qpython apk using the command: adb install
4. After the apk is successfully installed, verify the installation by checking the org.qpython.qpy directory on the board. the directory contains python binaries.
5. Before running python, we need to source the init.sh script in the bin/ directory: source init.sh
6. You can now run python by the following command from the bin/directory as: python-android5 /path/to/python/file.py